# oracle adf fusion application welcome page

Tags: java, oracle-adf

I am new to oracle fusion development using oracle adf framework.

Well my question is that when we create a project we have two projects inside first one is model and the other one is viewcontroller.I have a made a task flow and deployed it on a jspx page.When I run the application it pops me a box for target file, is there any posibility to make a welcome file where I just start the application and the application starts with that welcome jspx page.I have also defined a jspx page in welcome file list in viewcontroller's web.xml file but it continuously asking me about the target file to run.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to Shay's comments, you can try below option also,
Go to ViewController project properties >Run/Debug/Profile option>Default configuration>Enter 
appropriate page in "Default Run Target"

Answer (score 0):

You can right click your specific JSPX file and run it directly.
Or alternatively when the " box for target file" pops up - just choose your JSPX file and make it the default run target.